# Angular2 - Typehead select options not appearing

Tags: angular, firebase, typehead

I have the following [Angular 2 Typehead](http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/typeahead) declaration in my `component.html`

```
<input formControlName="location" [typeahead]="states" typeaheadOptionsLimit="7" typeaheadMinLength="4" placeholder="Please enter your postcode" 
                class="form-control" (keyup)="postcodeChanged()">
```

This is located within a form, as you can see I have added an additional event which is `(keyup)` when the user enters their postcode a call to the `.ts` file is made which is as shown:

```
postcodeChanged() {

    var enteredPostcode = this.editProfileForm.value['location'];

    if (enteredPostcode.length == 4) {

        this.states = [];

        this.service.getLocation(enteredPostcode).subscribe(response => {

            response.forEach(entry => {
                this.states.push({
                    id: entry.Id, description: entry.Description
                });
            })


            console.log('states value is', this.states);

        });
    }

}
```

This method, calls a service which connect to `Firebase` and retrieves the locations that match the postcode supplied. when I `console.log('states value is', this.states);` I see the correct values, however the `typehead` dropdown allowing the end user to select their address does not appear for some reason.

`this.states` is declared as `public states: Options[] = [];` at the top of my `.ts` file.  I'm uncertain into why this would not fire? the array is populated, `states` is referenced within the `.html`

Can anyone spot what I've missed?

**Update**

So setting

`[typeaheadWaitMs]="800"` on the input field seems to have done the trick, however I understand this is async process so if someone could help me resolve this to make it a bit cleaner instead of delaying the call it'll be great.

Comment: You can directly assign observable to `states` object like `this.states=this.service.getLocation(enteredPostcode)`

Comment: Yeah I know, however that still does not resolve the issue I'm currently experiencing.